# Configuring VCS of Teamcity for code checkout

Tags: version-control, teamcity

I am trying to specify rather complicated labeling rule in VCS of Teamcity. Not sure if what I am trying to do is possible or not.

This is my directory structure I have inherited.

```
mysvn/abc/repos
    |
    -TestDomain
    -TestSystem
     |
      -MyFrameWork
      -MySoftware
         |  
          -MySoftwareDevices
          -MySoftwareFiles
                       |
                       -branches
                       -tags
                       -trunk1
     -MySoftwareDriver
         |
          - branches
          - tags
          - trunk2
```

I want to specify such a rule that in the working directory of the checkout directory of Teamcity has structure like this:

```
 Teamcity checkout directory
  |
   -FolderA
   -FolderB
```

Where FolderA has contents of trunk1 and FolderB has contents of trunk2.

Is it possible to be done?

SVN URL like:
mysvn/abc/repos/TestSystem/MySoftware/MySoftwareFiles/trunk1

does give me trunk1. But I need contents of trunk1 and trunk2 under two different folders in the same build checkout directory.

Labeling I have been using: trunk=>tags

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the thing working. Its kind of hit and trial. Hoping someone comes up with proper explanations.

Labeling rules still has:

```
 trunk=>tags
```

The SVN URL : mysvn/abc/repos/TestSystem

It is the checkout rules which I added:

```
-:.
+:MySoftware/MySoftwareFiles/trunk1=>MyDir/FolderA
+:MySoftware/MySoftwareDriver/trunk2=>MyDir/FolderB
```